# Rails how to run rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

How do I run this rake file in terminal/console?

my statistik.rake in lib/tasks

```
desc "Importer statistikker"
namespace :reklamer do
  task :iqmedier => :environment do
    ...
  end
  task :euroads => :environment do
    ...
  end
  task :mikkelsen => :environment do
    ...
  end
  task :orville => :environment do
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You can run Rake tasks from your shell by running:

```
rake task_name
```

To run from from Ruby (e.g., in the Rails console or another Rake task):

```
Rake::Task['task_name'].invoke
```

To run multiple tasks in the same namespace with a single task, create the following new task in your namespace:

```
task :runall => [:iqmedier, :euroads, :mikkelsen, :orville] do
  # This will run after all those tasks have run
end
```

Comment: How do I rake all the tasks at once or do I need to change the namespace to a task?

Comment: If you want to run all the tasks at once make task :all => [:a, :b, :c] and then run rake reklamer:all

Comment: That wasn't part of your question, but you'd have to make a new task that calls each of them, which there is a shorthand for. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall, btw, you can use `task :runall => Rake::Task.tasks` if you want to run all the tasks. But this line must be declared after all tasks.

Comment: Where should the task :runall => go?

Comment: @tzown, as I said in my answer, it should go in the same namespace as the other tasks you want it to run.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall One potential pitfall of running multiple tasks like your ```:runall``` example above is that it will fail if any of the individual tasks fail

Comment: @thoughtpunch Right, because they’re dependencies of the task.

Comment: what are the pitfalls of running the task from ruby?

Comment: If you're passing parameters from the command line on Mac/Linux, ensure that you escape the square brackets like so:

rake my_task\\[1234\\]

Comment: @oddmeter Whether `[` and `]` need some form of escaping depends on your shell. Generally, though, I would suggest surrounding in single-quotes rather than awkward backslash-escaping.

Answer (score 30):

```
Rake::Task['reklamer:orville'].invoke
```

or

```
Rake::Task['reklamer:orville'].invoke(args)
```

Comment: This approach will work, but the "correct" way to bundle up raks tasks was answered by @andrew-marshall.

Comment: please provide reference if you're going to say something like 'the "correct" way...'. my answer was a response to the original question.

Comment: As a theoretical test, I tried running `Rake::Task['db:seed'].invoke` but it does not run, saying "Don't know how to build task 'db:seed'"

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49400110/7037546) if you get the error "_Don't know how to build task_"

Answer (score 29):

Sometimes Your rake tasks doesn't get loaded in console, In that case you can try the following commands

```
require "rake"
YourApp::Application.load_tasks
Rake::Task["Namespace:task"].invoke
```

Comment: Those quotes are bad but I can't edit them because it is too small an edit!

Comment: Even though this is not a real answer to the question asked. This is what I have been looking for and solved my problem (YourApp::Application.load_tasks). Thanks!

Comment: `Rails.application.load_tasks` (instead of `YourApp::Application.load_tasks`) can also be used, to be slightly more generic.

Answer (score 24):

Have you tried `rake reklamer:iqmedier` ?

My custom rake tasks are in the lib directory, not in lib/tasks. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: I want to run all tasks at once

Answer (score 16):

If you aren't sure how to run a rake task, first find out first what tasks you have and it will also list the commands to run the tasks.

Run `rake --tasks` on the terminal.

It will list the tasks like the following:

```
rake gobble:dev:prime             
rake gobble:dev:reset_number_of_kits                                    
rake gobble:dev:scrub_prod_data
```

You can then run your task with: `rake gobble:dev:prime` as listed.

Answer (score 4):

As the https://stackoverflow.com/a/5641807/7262646 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/49400110/7262646 described

you have to add

```rb
require 'rake'
Rake::Task.clear
YourAppName::Application.load_tasks
```

on the top of the file.

`YourAppName` comes from `config/applicaion.rb`, which is defined as a namespace, such as:

```
module YourAppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
  end
end
```

and then you can use

```rb
Rake::Task["task_name"].invoke
```

to invoke your task.

Answer (score 1):

In rails 4.2 the above methods didn't work.

1. Go to  the Terminal.
2. Change the directory to the location where your rake file is present.
3. run rake task_name.
4. In  the above case, run rake iqmedier - will run only iqmedir task.
5. run rake euroads - will run only the euroads task.
6. To Run all the tasks in that file assign the following inside the 
   same file and run rake all

   ```
   task :all => [:iqmedier, :euroads, :mikkelsen, :orville ] do #This will print all the tasks o/p on the screen 
   end
   ```