# Run a rake task upon saving a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, rake-task

I have a few files in a project that require post-processing each time they are updated.

I can extract these processes into a rake task. My question is:

**How can a rake task be run automatically every time a specific file is saved?**

Comment: why rake task, use some after_save callbacks with the processing you want to perform

Comment: @Bijendra I need to run some terminal commands. I assume those aren't possible with `after_save`.

Comment: What if you invoke the task like `Rake::Task['task_name'].invoke` on save

Comment: @TonyVincent I don't know what the invoke statement means. How do you implement it?

Comment: @sscirrus ok, check the ans if it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be able to do this using [invoke](http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/Task.html#M000119) method

```
if @file.save
  .
  .
  .
  Rake::Task['task_name'].invoke
end
```

see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641747/rails-how-to-run-rake-task) for more info

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your model file.

```
  after_save :update_rake_operations

  def update_rake_operations
    task = "update_status"
    Rake::Task[task].invoke
  end
```

You should have the below code in Rakefile under project folder. This should be present by default.

```
  require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
  require 'rake'

  ProjectFolder::Application.load_tasks
```

Comment: This applies to saving a record in the database, not a file.