# How do I run a Rake task using migration in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rails-migrations

I would like to run a Rake task using migration in Rails. Every time the command `rails db:migrate` is executed *the* task will run via migration.

The current Rake task is as follows.

```rb
namespace :task_for_log do
    desc 'This task sets current date as a default for logs where log_date is nil'
    task set_by_default_date_of_log: :environment do
        Log.where('log_date IS NULL').each do |log|
            log.update_attributes(log_date: log.created_at.to_date)
        end
    end
end
```

How do I use a migration file to run that task?

Comment: why using rake task here if your intention is to use migration?These `updates` can be part of migration themselves

Comment: because this is a requirement of my client therefore I need this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Migrations are really just Ruby files following a convention, so if you want to run a rake task inside of them you can just call the Rake class.

```
class ExampleMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    Rake::Task['task_for_log'].invoke
  end
end
```

However, migration files should be used specifically to handle the database schema. I would rethink how you are approaching the problem for a better solution. For example, you could run a SQL statement that updates your log attributes instead of calling a rake task.

```
class ExampleMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    execute <<-SQL
      UPDATE logs SET log_date = created_at WHERE log_date IS NULL
    SQL
  end
end
```

References:

- [Rails how to run rake task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641747/rails-how-to-run-rake-task)
- https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Comment: I'm using PGSql could you please convert in to according to this?

Comment: Sure, I updated it. I don't know what your `logs` table is named so you may need to change it accordingly. Here is the reference I used: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/practical-postgresql/9781449309770/ch04s05.html

Comment: run just remove table from SQL command. thanks it's working fine.

Comment: @JosephCho Up-voting for appropriate one. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to run your task *after* you run `db:migrate` automatically, you can use `enhance`.

```
Rake::Task['db:migrate'].enhance do
  # This task runs after every time you run `db:migrate`
  Rake::Task['task_for_log:set_by_default_date_of_log'].invoke
end
```

For a rails application, you can put this anywhere inside `lib/tasks` folder or put your task inline (inside of the `.enhance do` block)

Answer (score 1):

You can go as @joseph mention better solution! Or create custom task for it.

#### rake:

```
rake cm:set_by_default_date_of_log
```

#### task:

```
#lib/tasks/cm.rake
#custom_migration
namespace :cm do
  desc "This task set by default as current date for those logs where log_date is nil"
  task set_by_default_date_of_log: ['db:migrate'] do
    Log.where("log_date IS NULL").each do |log|
      log.update_attributes(log_date: log.created_at.to_date)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: but my client this approach is not good because we have to run this task by manual command therefore we have to make a migration file where this task run